# Debian routing with multiple connections

Tags: linux, debian, routing

In the past I had my router at home (debian server) who was acting as a DHCP server, DNS server and NAT between Internet and my network. Now, I need to replicate this at the office where I work. However, I have different parameters needed now.

We have two internet connections: one cable and one VDSL. We want to be able to receive both connection into our debian server (so 2 inputs) but only keep one network in our LAN (so 1 output). However, we want specific computer (IP from 10 to 20) to access Internet A and specific computer (IP from 21 to 30) to access Internet B. We do not need failover and/or loadbalacing.

I did my research on Google and I have found tutorials about how to do "multiple connection" part. I am about to try it. But the problem I have is to assign a specific computer to a specific Internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

Simply setup multiple route tables, one per ISP.  Then use `ip rule` to setup rules that select the route table based on the source address, or any other criteria that `ip rule` supports.

Rules might be as simple as something like

```
ip rule from 10.0.1.0/24 lookup table1
ip rule from 10.0.2.0/24 lookup table2
```

See:

- http://www.lartc.org/
- http://www.lartc.org/lartc.html#LARTC.RPDB.MULTIPLE-LINKS

Comment: That the thing. My boss want to keep computers on the same network/subnet. I have doubt this can be done... 10.0.0.1 will use `Internet A` but 10.0.0.2 will use `Internet B`

Comment: The rules aren't pointing to a subnet.  They are just CIDR notation to define a range of addresses.  You should define your address ranges so they are easily fit in a CIDR range instead of picking base10 ranges.  Also a 32 bit mask matches a single address so 10.1.1.1/32 = 10.1.1.1.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. Ok, I will try this. I'll get back to you. Thanks a lot.